# Controlling streaming on VLC from Android application

Tags: android, streaming, video-streaming, vlc

I'm using VLC for streaming on my server (Windows). I want integrate in my android application a control for manage the streaming (e.g. stop/start the  stream), remotely. something like done by the app: VLC Remote http://maketecheasier.com/remote-control-vlc-with-android-phone/2010/08/06

How can I implement something like VLC remote in my app?

Comment: I want know what can I do in order to control remotely the streaming. Can I use the vlc API?